# Statistical significance between retailer vs peers monthly satisfaction scores

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have a chart shown below of 2 retailers where consumer satisfaction scores have been captured for the same product.  These scores were tracked monthly for both retailers through the month of June (i.e. Jan-June or 1-6 in the x-axis below).

I have both the satisfaction scores and the sample sizes for each retailer.  This will become an ongoing process for many retailers and I would like to know a fast and easy code for calculating the statistical significance between both retailers for each month.  I would like to do this in R software.

I'm hoping someone can at least direct me to a similar code.  For the data set there is raw data with columns DATE, MONTH, SATISFACTION SCORE, RETAILER.

Please help me :-)

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Paired t-Test, which is described this tutorial: http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf. It is a variant of the Student's t-Test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples.  This tests whether there is a statistically significant difference between the average (mean) satisfaction ratings between two retailers.  Important: the distribution of *differences between ratings* for each month needs to be *approximately* Normal, i.e. roughly symmetric, single mode near the mean, and tails that are thin.  In simple terms, it must look like a bell curve, roughly.

Here is a web page that walks through an example of a Paired t-Test in R: http://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_09.html.

---

Please be aware that *statistical significance* is not the same as *practical significance*, a.k.a. "effect size".  I might be that Retailer A has statistically significantly better satisfaction than Retailer B, but the magnitude of the difference (effect size) might still be very small -- say 8.9 vs. 8.7.  The *only* thing that statistical significance tells you is that the difference you are seeing is not likely due to random variation in your data.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.  This makes sense and I can think about integrating the R code into a larger code to run the figures.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MikeM You are welcome.  Feel free to "up vote" my answer and flag it as "answered".  We love the reputation points! ;-)